# How to use the form value in php function?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am newbie to php.I have coded auto-complete text box using php,and i have a submit button.i have not given form action.

This is the HTML form code that i used for autocomplete textbox.this autocomplete textbox selects the value

```
<form  method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <p>
        <b>Theater Name</b> <label>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="theater" id="theater" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I have another php function that retrieves the values based on where clause.in the where statement i want to use selected value from form.

for ex: select address from theaters where theater_name ="form value"

How to use the form value in php function?can any one help me?

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("theaterdb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM theter
WHERE theater_name="<!-- This could be value that we get after clicking submit button-->);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['thearer_name'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
?>
```

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Not directly related, but given the fact that you're new to PHP, you'd do well _not_ to use the functions that have begun the deprecation process, like `mysql_*`. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Both of which allow you to deal with possible injection a lot better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the value from `$_POST` by `$_POST['theater']`.

And note, you should not use this value directly in the sql, you need to escape it to prevent sql injection.

```
$theater = mysql_escape_string($_POST['theater']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM theter WHERE theater_name='$theater'";
```

Last, you could take a look at [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which is suggested over the old `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, try using mysqli instead of mysql (mysqli_query, mysqli_connect).  There are numerous security / speed advantages to using it and it has pretty much the exact same functionality.

While the above answers mention using $_POST['theater'] (the name of your input), be SURE to escape your post before putting it into your query.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "YOUR PASSWORD HERE", "YOUR DATABASE HERE");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

 // No need for this, please see the updated mysqli_connect as the 4th parameter selects your DB
 //mysqli_select_db("theaterdb", $con);

// Please notice the last parameter of the mysqli_real_escape_string is your Input's POST
$query = "SELECT * FROM theater WHERE theater_name=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['theater']);

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['thearer_name'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, change your submit button code to the following:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now, this is the code you should use for the query:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("theaterdb", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM theater
    WHERE theater_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['theater']) . "'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['theater_name'];
        echo "<br />";
    }        
}
```

First, I check that the user submitted the form. Then, I escape the data he has submitted and inserting it into your query.

*** *NOTE: All of what I've wrote is based on the assumption that the code is executed after the form is submitted.***

*** *ANOTHER NOTE: You should read about using PDO rather than MYSQL functions.***

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST["your_variable_name"] // for POST
$_GET["your_variable_name"] // for GET
```

For in-depth information please go to: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php